# How to enable "Share publicly" when uploading a file to Firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Firebase Storage uses Google Cloud Platform for storage. GCP allows the option "Share publicly" on files to be able to view such files in a browser.

Here is the [GCP documentation on this topic](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website).

Here you can see the option available via the GUI on the GCP console.

[image]

Is it possible to enable the public option when uploading a file via Firebase?

Edit: I've enabled public reading on the whole bucket although it's not ideal.

```
gsutil defacl ch -u allUsers:R gs://<bucket>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Firebase Storage, you're given two URLs that you can use to represent files:

```
// "Private" internal URL, only accessible through Firebase Storage API
// This is protected by Firebase Storage Security Rules & Firebase Auth
gs://bucket/object

// "Public" unguessable URL, accessible by anyone with the link
// This is secured because that token is *very* hard for someone to guess
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/bucket/object?alt=media&token=<token>
```

The second option allows you to share this public but unguessable URL with trusted individuals, and allows them to access content without authentication to Firebase or using your app--think sharing family photos with Google Photos. Likely this behavior will be good enough, unless you desire public sharing with clean URLs.

The third option, as you mention, involves going directly to the Google Cloud Storage console and making files publicly available with a clean URL, which isn't available via the Firebase Storage client. This would add a  third URL:

```
// "Public" clean URL, accessible and guessable
// Not secure, typically used for public, static content
https://storage.googleapis.com/v0/bucket/object
```

Generally speaking, unless you want people to know and guess your content (hosting static content, website files, etc.), I **would not** share publicly via GCS, and almost definitely wouldn't go so far as to set the default ACL to always be public (what happens if you add a new feature and no longer want this behavior, you may forget to turn this back off again...).

Comment: So your answer is that you can't set a file to public using Firebase?

A problem with the session URL is that if the file is an HTML it won't display it's images and CSS files.

Comment: My answer is that #2 is public, and can be dropped in an `img` tag or imported as a CSS source no problem. `<img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/bucket/object?alt=media&token=<token>">` is totally valid and works (see https://github.com/mcdonamp/flaming-specs/blob/master/index.html#L59 if you don't believe me ;)

Comment: #2 can be used anywhere #3 can be used, but has additional security associated with it. The benefits of #3 would be if you're using the file as a static asset AND desire a clean URL; otherwise, I'd push for just using #2.

Comment: The question is if you can enable the public flag of GCP using Firebase or not...

Comment: If you want clean URLs in #3, you must go to GCP to enable this, Firebase doesn't allow you to enable this directly from our console.

Comment: Thanks, if you put that into your answer I will accept it. The problem is not really getting clean URLs in the html files, but in all its static dependencies. Using #3 isn't really ideal. It would be great if this could be enabled per file when uploading via Firebase.

Comment: I think that you want to use Firebase Hosting (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) for this solution, as it looks like you're building a website or hosting other static assets. As mentioned before, Storage URLs in #2 provide all the benefits of #3 (sharability, ease of download, inclusion in HTML), minus clear URLs, since Hosting generally covers that use case. I doubt that we'll include it in our API for that reason (plus it can be enabled via GCS when someone has a different use case). Maybe I just don't understand your use case?

Comment: I'm not building a website, but an ebook publishing system in HTML. The authors need to be able to view and edit those HTML files. Since the HTMLs will be viewed somewhere else in their final form solution #2 is not viable. We need clean URLs, and the public attribute set on a per file basis.

Comment: @Mike, what I noticed when serving images via #2 is it's very slow (almost double latency) compared to #3.